# Raspberry-pi remote connection using putty, GUI not working

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, raspberry-pi, xming

On my Client PC I’m running Windows 8.1 and I have installed XMing. I am running Putty and I have configured it to enable X11 Forwarding. I have tried leaving the X display location blank (as default) and also with the value “:0.0” minus the quotations. My raspberry pi is running Linux. I edited the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file to include the following two lines: ForwardX11 yes ForwardX11Trusted yes

I have also copied the '.Xauthority' file to /root. I also installed xauth using “sudo apt-get install xauth” Whenever I try to run an application, like “xterm &” or xclock I get the same error: PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol Error: Can’t open display: localhost:10.0

I’ve combed the Internet and found a number of other people reporting the same problem, but no clear fix, at least that has worked for me. Anybody else solved this problem?